# How to prove that it can be : $ρ=(a+d)\cos θ + (b-c)\sin θ =0$ while $Δ<0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

**Note :** I avoided writing the whole expression of $Δ$ on the title, sorry for that.

**The following must be solved in the way described, since this is what the exercise asks.**

I was solving a problem of dynamical systems which came down to the following expressions, after some big calculations via Jacobians for the linearized system. My calculations are double checked and probably correct. I now have to prove a string of cases, so that I can determine the kind and the stability of $O(0,0)$, which I'm being asked to prove that it can be an : Asymptotically stable knot, Asymptotically Stable focus, Stable center, Unstable focus, Unstable knot, while $θ\in [0,π]$ and $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$.

From my Jacobian calculations, I've got that :

> $$ρ=(a+d)\cos θ + (b-c)\sin θ $$
>
> $$Δ=(a\cosθ-c\sinθ-b\sinθ-d\cosθ)^2 + 4(b\cosθ-d\sinθ)(a\sinθ+c\cosθ)$$

Starting from the case to be made, so that $O(0,0)$ is a stable center, I would need to prove that :

$$ρ=0$$

$$Δ<0$$

My question is : **How can I prove the statements above ? The system seems too complicated, with a ton of different cases, regarding constants, regarding $θ$ which can all vary.**

My attempt :

Starting from $ρ=0$, we have :

$$(a+d)\cosθ +(b-c)\sinθ=0 \Leftrightarrow (a+d)\cosθ=-(b-c)\sinθ \Leftrightarrow \tanθ=-\bigg(\frac{a+d}{b-c}\bigg)$$

In that case, I'm considering that $b-c \neq 0$, but getting a completely unknown $\tan^-1$ solution will not help me proving that $Δ<0$.

If it was $b-c=0$ then we would have that : $(a+d)\cosθ =0$ which either means that $a+d = 0$ or $\cosθ=0 \Rightarrow θ = nπ + π/2$ but since $θ\in \mathbb [0,π]$ , the only acceptable value is : $θ=π/2$

Now, for $θ=π/2$ $Δ$ becomes :

$$Δ=(-c -b)^2 -4da$$

which would be $<0$ if : $(-c-b)^2 < 4da $. I guess this can hold, since $a,b,c,d$ are unrestricted constants.

But even like this, there is still another case (vice versa, with $a+d=0$) and still I cannot seem to prove what happens when $(a+d),(b-c) \neq 0$

Moreover than that, there are still many different cases that should be checked on the other kinds of $O(0,0)$ which really makes it an incredibly huge exercise which could mean there could be an easier way proving such systems (like the one I got from the Stable center case, $ρ=0,Δ<0$.

I would really appreciate any help since I'm stuck on how to proceed. I don't need help for all the points, I just need a hint or a thorough explanation on how to handle such a system, since all the other points could probably work the same way around.

A final question is, does finding such values for $a,b,c,d$ (at least if there are specific) mean that a conclusion could be made ? In this case, I would not need to proceed with all the different cases. (I'm asking this, because when in other exercises we work with Lyapunov Functions involving constants, finding even specific constants that fullfill our needs, leads us to a general result. So if that's the case here, it could be simplified a lot.)

Comment: If $c=b$ and $d=-a$, then $ρ=0$ and $Δ=4a^2+4b^2\ge 0$.

Comment: @mathlove True ! But (1) we need $Δ<0$ for the case discussed (although this one works for one of the other stability kinds mentioned). This, though, would be part of my last question, does a specific value of the system (ignoring all the other cases) lead us to a general conclusion without needing to check every different case ?

Comment: It seems to me that if you can find constants $a,b,c,d$ that make $\rho =0$ and $\Delta < 0$, then you've shown $O(0,0)$ can be a stable centre.

Comment: @B.Mehta Well if that's the case, then it's simplified a lot ! Just what I was asking at the last part. If, though, you need to consider every possible outcome, it's really complicated.

Comment: I am far from the topic, so I would not be helpful for you on it, but my calculations showed that the expression for $\Delta$ can be simplified to $\Delta=\rho^2+4(bc-ad)$.